# Jenkinsfile declarative script git plugin: how to set shallow clone and depth attributes

Tags: plugins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I've a declarative pipeline in Jenkinsfile where I'd line to add the shallow clone option,  depth = 1, timeout = 30 in the git plugin. Currently my setup that is working is:

```
            git(
                credentialsId: 'MY_GIT_CREDENTIALS', 
                branch: "${params.BRANCH}", 
                url: "${env.BBSCM}"
            )
```

Could somebody help me adding to the statement the three desired parameters ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable these additional customization options, you need to utilize the full and recommended [SCM Step checkout method](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) with the `GitSCM` class. After consulting the documentation, we see that the syntax and usage for your current and desired arguments would appear like:

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM',
  branches: [[name: "*/${params.BRANCH}"]],
  extensions: [[
    $class: 'CloneOption',
    shallow: true,
    depth:   1,
    timeout: 30
  ]],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[
    url:           params.SCM_URL,
    credentialsId: 'MY_GIT_CREDENTIALS'
  ]]
])
```

If you are new to Jenkins Pipeline, and this syntax and usage appears intimidating, note that in the future you can also use the [Pipeline Syntax Snippet Generator](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) for assistance.

Comment: In your answer, you don't specify the `refspec` option inside `userRemoteConfigs`, so you will end up fetching all branches !
`userRemoteConfigs: [[refspec: '+refs/heads/' + params.BRANCH + ':refs/remotes/origin/' + params.BRANCH,url: params.SCM_URL,credentialsId: 'MY_GIT_CREDENTIALS'`


Without, you will see : `git fetch --no-tags --progress --depth=1 ... +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

And with : `git fetch --no-tags --progress --depth=1 ... +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop`

Comment: I've proposed a modification of your answer @matthew-schuchard